# Pandas replace() on all masked values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace 'bee' with 'ass' on all masked values `m` in `df`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Data1':[899, 900, 901, 902],
        'Data2':['as-bee', 'be-bee', 'bee-be', 'bee-as']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   Data1   Data2
0    899  as-bee
1    900  be-bee
2    901  bee-be
3    902  bee-as

wrong = {'Data1':[900,901]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(wrong)

   Data1
0    900
1    901

m = df['Data1'].isin(wrong['Data1'])

df[m]['Data2'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('bee','aas'))

1    be-aas
2    aas-be
Name: Data2, dtype: object
```

It returns the desired changes, but the values in `df` does not change. Doing `df[m]['Data2']=df[m]['Data2'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('bee','aas'))` does not help either as it returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do this using

***Method1*** : **[`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):**

```
m=df.Data1.isin(df1.Data1) # boolean mask
df.loc[m,'Data2']=df.loc[m,'Data2'].replace('bee','ass',regex=True)
print(df)
```

***Method2:*** **[`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)**

```
m=df.Data1.isin(df1.Data1)
df.Data2=np.where(m,df.Data2.replace('bee','ass',regex=True),df.Data2)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Data1   Data2
0    899  as-bee
1    900  be-ass
2    901  ass-be
3    902  bee-as
```